# Filter rows if one column or more are empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a CSV with 3 columns and if a row has an empty value in any of the las two columns it should be filtered.'m trying to create a script in Linux that given two arguments, a txt file and a number, extracts the multiples of the number in the list and sums them.

```
f1 f2 f3
a, b, c
d,  , e
f, g, 
h, i, j
```

I have tried with:

```
cut d"," -f2.3 file.csv | grep -v ",,"
```

and

```
cut d"," -f2.3 file.csv | grep .
```

But the first one doesn't filter anything and the second only works if I cut a single column.

It should look like this:

```
f2 f3
b, c
i, j
```

And I can't use awk.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Just edited to put the expected output

Comment: The source don't look like a CSV.

Comment: In general, CSV files are to complicated for standard tools like awk, grep, sed, ..., because of possible quoting, escaping and split of logical line into multiple physical lines. Best is to use tools that can manage CSV like python or php. So standard can only manage CSV, if a simple form is guaranteed.

Comment: Thank for the reply but i must use tools like grep and cut since it's the rules of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example CSV given in the question, it can be done using `egrep`

**Code:**

```
egrep -v ',  |, $' /your/example.csv
```

**Output:**

```
f1 f2 f3
a, b, c
h, i, j
```

Answer (score 0):

With any `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF==3' file
f1 f2 f3
a  b  c
h  i  j
```

If it's really comma separated, use `-F,`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NF==3' file
```

---

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -ane 'print if @F == 3' file
f1 f2 f3
a  b  c
h  i  j
```

or

```
$ perl -F, -ane 'print if @F == 3' file
```

---

Using just `shell` loop:

```
$ while IFS=, read c1 c2 c3; do
    [[ $c3 ]] && echo "$c1 $c2 $c3"
 done < file

f1 f2 f3
a, b, c
h, i, j
```

Comment: My issue is that i can't use awk.

Comment: Which OS? Why not?

Comment: See my Perl's solution

Comment: It's a rule for the project, i'm using linux.

Comment: So Perl and awk are installed by default on most distros

Comment: Yes I know, if i could use these tools i would have solved it. But I must not use them.

Comment: OK, you should say it's a class lesson or homework. The last solution use only shell

Comment: Have you tested the latest shell code?